# How can I transpose multiple lines of data into strings with a unidue ID?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transpose

I have a file with millions of rows that I need to convert. I'm having trouble getting a desired result so I wanted to defer to the experts;

```
select
[ID],
min ([date]) as 'Payment1',
min ([date]) as 'Payment2', 
where 'Payment2' > 'Payment1'
min ([date]) as 'Payment3', 
where 'Payment3' > 'Payment2'
min ([date]) as 'Payment4', 
where 'Payment4' > 'Payment3'
from [FP&A].[dbo].[PaymentSchedules]
group by [ID]
order by [ID]
```

Comment: I'm still learning syntax, but I'm hoping that this is easy enough to understand what I'm attempting to pull off. If this looks completely off, my sincerest apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to select the four lowest distinct dates as your four payments. I will present an easy to understand way to get this:

1. Find payment1
2. join to the table again to find payment2
3. join to the table again to find payment3
4. ...

The end result is here:

```
with step1 as (
  select id, min(date) as payment1
  from ps
  group by id
), step2 as (
  select step1.*, min(date) as payment2
  from step1
  join ps on step1.id = ps.id
  where step1.payment1 < ps.date
  group by step1.id, payment1
), step3 as (
  select step2.*, min(date) as payment3
  from step2
  join ps on step2.id = ps.id
  where step2.payment2 < ps.date
  group by step2.id, payment1, payment2
), step4 as (
  select step3.*, min(date) as payment4
  from step3
  join ps on step3.id = ps.id
  where step3.payment3 < ps.date
  group by step3.id, payment1, payment2, payment3
)
select * from step4
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66576/8

Now this makes 4 joins, so the performance isn't the best. If you are having problems with performance, then I would look into ranking the dates, picking the four lowest (excluding duplicates), and then pivoting the table.

Answer (score 0):

So a friend of a friend knew what I was working on and came up with this code that did the trick in 2 steps. I'm posting it in case it helps somebody else in the future;

```
Select [DBO].[ID], 
[DBO].[Date], 
count(*) as 'alias1'
into ##Temp
from [DBO] left outer join [DBO] as 'alias2'
on [DBO].[ID] = [alias2].[id]
And [DBO].[Date] >= [alias2].[Date]
Group BY [dbo].[id], 
     [dbo].[Date]
order by [dbo].[ID], [dbo].[alias1]


Select ##Temp.id, 
MIN(case when [alias1] = 1 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment1,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 2 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment2,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 3 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment3,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 4 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment4,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 5 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment5,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 6 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment6,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 7 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment7,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 8 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment8,
MIN(case when [alias1] = 9 then Date Else NULL END) as Payment9
from ##
group by ##Temp.id
order by ##Temp.id
```